# Payment method not working properly in cs cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway, checkout, cs-cart

I create a new payment gateway in cscart. After get success result from payment gateway cs cart redirect it to checkout page and show incomplete checkout.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please narrow down your question to what payment gateway you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide any code, I made an example code for processing the response:

```
if ($mode == 'return') {
    // this means, that the payment processor returned from 3rd party checkout page

    $order_info = fn_get_order_info($_REQUEST['order_id'], true);

    // you should have a response code (this section depends on your payment gateway)
    if ($_REQUEST['response_code'] == "S") {
        // the transaction was successful!
        $pp_response['order_status'] = 'P';
        $pp_response['transaction_id'] = $_REQUEST['transaction_id'];
        $pp_response["reason_text"] = $_REQUEST['response_code'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['transaction_id']);


        fn_finish_payment($_REQUEST['order_id'], $pp_response, false);
        fn_order_placement_routines('route', $_REQUEST['order_id']);
    } else {
        // the transaction was NOT successful!
        $pp_response['order_status'] = 'N';
        $pp_response['transaction_id'] = $_REQUEST['transaction_id'];
        $pp_response["reason_text"] = $_REQUEST['response_code'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['transaction_id']);

        fn_order_placement_routines('route', $_REQUEST['order_id'], false);
    }
}
```

The key "functions" are: `fn_finish_payment()` and `fn_order_placement_routines()`. If you did not finish the payment, you will be redirected to the checkout page, because this means, something went wrong.